# Cannot "make" verlihub on Debian

Tags: c++, makefile, debian

I'm trying to create my own dchub on Debian using Verlihub. Everything works great when I'm using ./configure but when I'm trying to "make", it ends with an error! Please help!

./configure gives back:

```
Configure has completed successfully. Now you must run make.
If make fails with errors, please consult the forums and see
if anyone else has had the same issue. The forums are located
here http://forums.verlihub-project.org
Extensive documentation is also available at the project website
which can be found here http://www.verlihub-project.org
Please feel free to join and register at the Verlihub suport
hub located here dchub://hub.verlihub-project.org:7777
```

**sudo make** gives back:

```
stringutils.cpp: In function 'void nStringUtils::ExpandPath(std::string&)':
stringutils.cpp:127:31: error: 'get_current_dir_name' was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [stringutils.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/verlihub-0.9.8e-r2/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/verlihub-0.9.8e-r2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: 'The forums are located
here http://forums.verlihub-project.org' => have you tried there?
The error is clearly:
stringutils.cpp:127:31: error: 'get_current_dir_name' was not declared in this scope
ie line 127 character 31.  beyond that noone can really help based of the info you've provided

Comment: http://www.verlihub-project.org/doc/page/manual.installation has specific debian sections ++ a installation walkthrough

Comment: On the side note: you should *never* use `sudo make`, always build under current user and only install as root, *if needed*

Comment: @Erbureth, I tried it under root and I still get that error. That's not the problem.

Comment: @tolanj - Verlihub forums doesn't work anymore. What info should I bring to get some help?

Comment: @DooMFeaR *Don't* build under root. As I said, this is only side note, I do not know, where the problem lies.

Comment: @Erbureth I tried on a different user but that didn't helped me :(. Any other ideas?